# I18n.locale in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I am successfully setting I18n.locale in my app but the problem arise when I want to use it:

```
 @categories = Category.where(:tld => I18n.locale).all
```

then I am getting strange sql condition:

```
 SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."tld" = '--- :com')
```

however when I do
     logger.info(I18n.locale)
I am getting correct output:

```
  com
```

I am new to rails and ruby and it looks like I am not accessing string value of I18n.locale.

Comment: Have you tried I18n.locale.to_s?

Answer (score 0):

I found simple and obvious solution:

```
 I18n.locale.to_s
```

Is there any simpler method?

Answer (score 0):

I've got problems with radiant globalize2 extension. I've to add it in to places where conditions for find are created

`I18n.locale.to_s`

works for me